# Cntrolling Access using Spring Security3.1

Tags: spring, spring-security

In my project I'm using spring security3.1 I'm attaching my spring security file herewith:

```
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="SELECT user_name,user_password,account_status FROM systemuser WHERE user_name=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="SELECT user_name,authority FROM systemuser WHERE user_name=?"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
   </beans:beans>
```

its working fine.now my requirement is I want to customize the asscess of the users.For example I have 3 anchor tag as follows:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/manageUsers" id="user_link">Manage  Users</a></td>
<td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/allcontact">Manage Contact</a></td>
<td><a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />" > Logout</a></td>
</tr>
```

now,I want admin will have access to all of these 3 tabs(or link) that will take them to the corresponding pages,but ROLE_USER (general user) will **not be able** to access the **'Manage Users "** tab.So I mean when a user with privilege  ROLE_ADMIN logs in all of the 3 link will be visible but when a User with privilege **"ROLE_USER"** logs in only 2 links i.e **"Manage Contacts" and "Logout"** will be visible.

how can I implement this can anyone suggest me????????

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I solved it by implementing my own AuthentificationProvider.

To do this you need to complete several steps:

1 Implement GrantedAuthority interface

```
public class UserAccessRole implements GrantedAuthority {

    private String accessRole;

    public UserAccessRole(String ar) {
        accessRole = ar;
    }

    public UserAccessRole(AdminUserRoleEnum ar) {
        accessRole = ar.toString();
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return accessRole;
    }

}
```

AccessRole is the name of user role in your system.

2 Implement your UserDetailService. This is your authentication provider. Here you should retrieve user from database(!Important: You should add user role in database and retrieve it with user). AdminUser this is my DAO class(You can name it like you want). Note that user class is the part of spring-security framework. User that you create here returns to spring-security and it finishes authentication process.

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

public class UserAuthenticationProvider implements UserDetailsService {

    @Resource(name = "adminUserDAO")
    AdminUserDAO adminDAO;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        AdminUser admin = adminDAO.getByName(name);
        User user = null;

        if (admin != null) {
            Set<UserAccessRole> roles = new HashSet<UserAccessRole>();
            roles.add(new UserAccessRole(admin.getRole()));

            user = new User(
                    admin.getName(),
                    admin.getPassword(),
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    roles
            );
        }

        return user;
    }

}
```

3 Somewhere in your Controller use this code for user redirection. User will receive page depends on it role:

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> name =   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
UserAccessRole role = (UserAccessRole) name.iterator().next();
if (role.getAuthority().equals(AdminUserRoleEnum.ADMIN_USER.toString())) {
   return "redirect:/admin_user_page/";
}
if (role.getAuthority().equals(AdminUserRoleEnum.USER.toString())) {
   return "redirect:/user_page";
}
```

4  Finally configure spring-security:

```
   <beans:bean id="userAuthentificationProvider"
                class="path_to.UserAuthentificationProvider">
    </beans:bean> 

   <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userAuthentificationProvider">
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Comment: I'm using database for retrieving user name and authority and password from your example it seems like you are not storing the credentials inside database you are using simple form based authentication. please give the code of your "userAuthentificationProvider" bean

Comment: Yes, I wrote this in step number 2.